# How do you pass a class into a method and return a boolean based on a parameter of the class?

Tags: java, class, methods, parameters, boolean

I am having trouble with a method taking in two class objects and returning a boolean value. I understand i need a return statement in each condition of my if statement, one returning false and another returning true. the issue im facing is each object has a (i, j) coordinate on a 10x10 multi-dimensional array grid. When both objects have the same (i, j) the game should end.

This is the method i am having trouble with. It takes in Creature c1 and Creature c2 and returns a boolean. What would i put in the method to make this  work?

```
public static boolean sameSquare(Creature c1, Creature c2) {
    // if c1 and c2 have identical (i, j) coordinates, return true
    // else return false
    c1 = Creature(human);
    c2 = Creature(vampire);
    if (c1 == c2) {
      return true;
      System.out.println("you bit the human");
    }else {
      return false;
    }

   }
```

The call to this method looks like this

```
sameSquare(human, vampire);
```

The creation of the objects human and vampire are as follows:

```
System.out.print("Enter (i, j) for vampire: ");
int newI = input.nextInt();
int newJ = input.nextInt();
Creature vampire = new Creature('V', newI, newJ);


System.out.print("Enter (i, j) for human: ");
int humanI = input.nextInt();
int humanJ = input.nextInt();
Creature human = new Creature('H', humanI, humanJ);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the isEqual method in your Creature class to customize how classes are compared.

In this case it looks like you'll want to compare each class's I and J positions.

However, it's a bit odd to consider these Creatures "equal" just because of their position. They're still different!

Perhaps define a method in your creature class like:

```
public Boolean hasSamePositionAsCreature( Creature other )
{ 
   if( other.I == this.I && other.J == this.J )
   {
       return true
   }

   return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use == on two objects your comparing references not values.

```
c1 = Creature(human);
c2 = Creature(vampire);
c1 == c2 // Will always be false!!
```

You need to override the equals method in the Creature class.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // You might also want to verify that o is an instance of Creature
    if (! (o instanceof Creature))
        return false;
    Creature other= (Creature) o;

    // Write logic to check if they are in the same cell
    if (this.i == other.i && this.j == other.j)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use **==** for object comparison, this will check address of objects instead of their contents.

In order to compare two objects you need to override **equals** method in your class and then do proper checking and return boolean accordingly. In your case **equals** method would be :

```
public boolean equals(Creature obj){
    if(obj!=null &&(this.i==obj.i && this.j==obj.j))
        return true
    else 
        return false;
}
```

Now you can compare two objects as shown below :

```
c1.equals(c2)
```